# iOS app to listen to a port all the time

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to create an app that listen to a custom port all the time & when the client try to connect through that port I want to handle that event.

I searched a lot in the internet about it but I couldn't get any good resources for my requirement.

I want to know if I build that app somehow, will Apple Store approve my app? because the app always listen to a port. They might think it's a security issue.

Can anyone give me an answer to that question, as well as please provide me relevant resources for that.

Thanks

Comment: You could not find any examples of a TCP server?

Comment: I found CocoaAsyncSocket as an example. But it is for Mac OSX & it is too much complex.

Comment: Before you go too much further, do you expect your app to be listening to a socket when it is not the currently running app? i.e. when the user is using another app, your app is still listening?  Because that isn't compatible with the iOS approach to multi-tasking

Comment: I only want the app to listening to a port when the app is on screen & running.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking about Apple's App Store policy rather than about a programming problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has some examples, both with Core Foundation and POSIX sockets in the [network programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/CH73-SW9) - but there is still a lot of work to be done beyond the code provided.

Because the use cases for mobile devices are typically client-style rather than server-style there isn't the same degree of development and examples available.

If the "other end" of your connection is also iOS, perhaps the multi peer connectivity framework could be an option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out: [Cocoa Asynch sockets by Robbie Hanson](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket). You can listen on a port and send/receive data on it.

Answer (score 0):

Http is the standard mode of communication in iOS and all requests are handled by port 80, however should you find the need to use specific ports or go a bit lower level than HTTP and communicate using TCP sockets to your own custom server it's very much possible.

The advantages of doing this are several:
You can send just the exact data you need to send – making your protocol lean and efficient.
You can send connected clients data whenever you want, rather than requiring the clients to poll.
You can write socket servers without a dependency of a web server, and can write in the language of your choice.

Here's a tutorial that might get you started.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

Comment: In this tutorial the app works as a client & python is the server. But I want the app to work as a server to waiting for a connection.

Comment: Agreed but this was just to get you started. The AFNetworking API is a third party iOS API you can look into, which lets you do a lot of low level calls as against the iOS 7 NSSession API.